# Perl DBI — download a hash format string on query

Tags: perl, dbi

I have a script that uses a custom module `EVTConf` which is just a wrapper around [`DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI). 
It has the username and password hard coded so we don't have to write the username and password in every script.

I want to see the data that the query picks up - but it does not seem to pick up anything from the query - just a `bless` statement.

What is `bless`?

```
#!/sbcimp/dyn/data/scripts/perl/bin/perl

use EVTConf;

EVTConf::makeDBConnection(production);
$dbh = $EVTConf::dbh;

use Data::Dumper;

my %extend_hash = %{@_[0]};

my $query = "select level_id, e_risk_symbol, e_exch_dest, penny, specialist from etds_extend";

if (!$dbh) {
    print "Error connecting to DataBase; $DBI::errstr\n";
}

my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "\n\nCould not prepare statement: ".$dbh->errstr;
$cur_msg->execute();
$cur_msg->fetchrow_array;

print Dumper($cur_msg) ;
```

This is what I get:

```
Foohost:~/walt $
Foohost:~/walt $ ./Test_extend_download_parse_the_object
$VAR1 = bless( {}, 'DBI::st' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$cur_msg` is a statement handle (hence it is blessed into class `DBI::st`).  You need something like:

```
my $cur_msg = $dbh->prepare($query) or die "…";
$cur_msg->execute();

my @row;
while (@row = $cur_msg->fetchrow_array)
{
    print "@row\n";
    # print Dumper(\@row);
}
```

only you need to be a bit more careful about how you actually print the data than I was.  There are a number of other fetching methods, such as `fetchrow_arrayref`, `fetchrow_hashref`, `fetchall_arrayref`.  All the details are available via `perldoc DBI` at the command line or the [`DBI`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) page on CPAN.

You can see what the official documentation says about `bless` by using `perldoc -f bless` (or going to [`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html)).  It is a way of associating a variable with a class, and the class in this example is `DBI::st`, the DBI statement handle class.  You `$dbh` would be in class `DBI::db`, for example.

---

> What is the best way to print the results?

The best way to print them out depends on what you know about the result set.

You might choose:

```
printf "%-12s  %6.2f\n", $row[0], $row[3];
```

if you know that there are only two fields you're interested in (though why didn't you just choose the two you're interested in — it costs time (a little time) to process elements 1 and 2 if they're unused).

You might choose:

```
foreach my $val (@row) { print "$val\n"; }
```

You might choose:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < scalar(@row); $i++)
{
    printf "%-12s  = %s\n", $cur_msg->{NAME}[$i], $row[$i];
}
```

to print out the column name as well as the value.  There are many other possibilities too, but those cover the key ones.

---

As noted by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149589/perl-dbi-download-a-hash-format-string-on-query/25149657?noredirect=1#comment39154820_25149657), you should be using `use strict;` and `use warnings;` automatically and reflexively in your Perl code.  There's one variable that is not handled strictly in the code you show, namely `$dbh`.  'Tis easily remedied; add `my` before it where it is assigned.  But it is a good idea to ensure that you use them all the time.  Using them can allows you to avoid unexpected behaviours that you weren't aware of and weren't intending to exploit.

Comment: why is the array row in parehthesis

Comment: Because I put them there.  In context, they are not necessary, but sometimes they are necessary: `my ($v1, $v2, @remainder) = @_;` for example.  I forgot to remove them.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  It's a real shame you didn't press using `strict` and `warnings`. Declaring everything in this program (and probably in `EVTConf.pm` too) would clarify things a lot

Comment: Yes, I should probably have mentioned it.  The only non-strict variable is `$dbh`, and that might be covered in the other module (though actually, more probably, given the assignment, it is not).   So, OK…I'll go back and add it.